# which network type should i use in UPC

Tags: upc

I want to run UPC program on my linux cluster with 4 nodes(each with 24 threads), UPC has provided "udp mpi and smp " netwrok when compiling the code. But in my case, which netwrok type should i use and how to write the machine file if i want to run 24 threads on one nodes.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run on a single node of any system, you can use smp conduit (the easiest to setup job spawning, it always just works with no setup).

Assuming this is an ethernet-connected cluster, then for 2 or more nodes you want udp conduit. This will require some setup depending on what other cluster software you have installed. The [upcrun documentation is here](https://upc.lbl.gov/docs/user/upcrun.html). If your `mpirun` is already setup to spawn jobs across your cluster nodes, then `upcrun` can use that to spawn udp conduit jobs with the following settings:

```
GASNET_SPAWNFN=C
GASNET_CSPAWN_CMD='mpirun -np %N %C'
```

Otherwise you'll need to setup passwordless ssh access to your cluster nodes and use ssh-based spawning, see [this tutorial](https://upc.lbl.gov/docs/user/sshagent.shtml).